# Count distinct values in array - performance tips

Tags: go, count, maps

I'm having some issues optimizing a go map.
I want to generate a frequency table (count distinct occurrences) in an array of strings. My code holds nicely for small arrays, but as I start working with 100k+ structures -with many distinct values- it just isn't performant enough.

Right now, my approach is to generate an array with the distinct values, compare values and increasing the counter variable (mapped to the string).

```
    counter := make( map[string]int )    
    for _, distinct := range distinctStrArray{
        for _, row := range StrArray{
            if (row == distinct){
                counter[distinct]++
            }  
        } 
    }
```

I've tried another approach, where with the input array previously sorted (to minimize the number of changes to the map). This is a bit faster.

```
    count:=0
    for _, distinct := range distinctStrArray{
        for _, row := range StrArray{
            if (row == distinct){
                count++
            }  
        } 
    counter[distinct] += count
    count= 0
    }
```

Do you have any suggestion of what I can do to optimize a simple *count(distinct)* type problem...? I'm open to anything.
thanks!

Comment: In the second example, you keep iterating after you find a match, which is needless if the input is sorted. If `row != distinct && count > 0` you can break, because that would be the first non-match after finding a match, and there can't be any more matches after that if the input is sorted.

Comment: What's the purpose of having two arrays? The map already guarantees distinct keys, why not just use that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without more context, I would dump the separate array of distinct values - generating it takes time, and using it necessitates the nested loop. Assuming there's no other purpose to the second array, I'd use something like:

```
counter := make( map[string]int )    
for _, row := range StrArray {
    counter[row]++
}
```

If you need the list of distinct strings without the counts for some separate purpose, you can easily get it afterward:

```
distinctStrings := make([]string, len(counter))
i := 0
for k := range counter {
    distinctStrings[i] = k
    i++
}
```

Iterating the array of distinct strings is O(n), while map access by key is O(log(n)). That takes your overall from O(n^2) to O(n*log(n)), which should be a significant improvement with larger datasets. But, as with any optimization: test, measure, analyze, optimize.

Comment: Map access by key is usually O(1) in case of hashmaps.

Comment: O(1)... ish? The Go spec makes no statement on performance. I guess I should say "*no worse than* O(log(n)) for the map access or O(n*log(n)) in total". Also some of the iterations won't just be lookups, they'll be inserts, which tend to take a little longer due to rebalancing etc. Regardless... way faster than O(n^2) for sure.